# Bind return value of Multivalueconverter to a property

Tags: c#, wpf, converters

I have a multivalue converter which takes two values, based on a logic either one of the value is returned. I wanted to whether i was possible to bind the return value to another property ?

```
<DatePicker SelectedDate="{BindingStartDateTime,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}"
    Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Width="100"
    DisplayDate="{Binding ElementName=cmbDOS, Path=SelectedItem.FromDate}"
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="2,2,2,2" >
    <DatePicker.SelectedDate>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource OperatorToListConverter}">
            <Binding Path="StartDateTime" />
            <Binding Path="SomeOtherDate"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </DatePicker.SelectedDate>
</DatePicker>
```

Based on my logic i will either select start or some date, and i want ithe value to reflect in StartDateTime. This obviously give error, is there any other way ?

Comment: That's called [MultiBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: You are not getting what i am trying to say. Suppose the above coverter is set on visibility property of a control, now what i wanted to ask is whether i can bind its return value to my own property which resides inside my viewmodel

Comment: You need `DependencyProperty` to use binding besides why can't you put that logic from converter into your view model?

Comment: That still seems a little vague.  The purpose of a value converter is to bind a property of one type to a property of another type on the control, or in the case of a multi converter, you are binding multiple view model properties to a control property.  So in your comment, you are almost answering your own question.  Try adding some code to further explain your question.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use an instance of your converter in the view model, where you want the value?:

```
SomeConverter converter = new Converter();
object[] values = {someObject.SomeProperty, someOtherObject.SomeProperty};
object result = 
    converter.Convert(values, typeof(SomeType), someParam, new CultureInfo("en-GB"));
```

Comment: Although this somewhat an answer to my question, but this property is inside a class, of which i have made a list. This list is binded to listview, a datatemplate is also binded to it which contains a combobox to which i have attached my converter

Comment: You ask a question, providing very few requirements and when someone actually takes the time to give you a 100% valid answer, you say it is only *somewhat an answer to my question*... well, perhaps you should ask a proper question, providing *all* of your requirements before you start complaining that answers don't fit your (previously unknown) requirements?

Comment: I am extremely sorry this. I thought there would a quick fix to the solution, so is posted only a small snippet of code. Posting the entire code would really take time, since the template is quite large.

Comment: Well this is what happens when a user asks a question, but doesn't provide all of their requirements... the question author doesn't get the right answer and the answer author just wastes their time.